# vavr: combine a large list of Validation<Error, ?> to a single Validation<Error, Reference>

Tags: java, vavr

I'm playing with vavr library in order to handle validation.

My question is how to combine a large number of field related validation to a single one.

I mean, here my `Reference` class:

```java
public class Reference {

    private final ReferenceUniqueIdentifier referenceUniqueIdentifier;
    private final TransactionId transactionId;
    private final DocumentId documentId;
    private final String field4;
    private final String field5;
    private final String field6;
    private final String field7;
    private final String field8;
    private final String field9;
    private final String field10;

}
```

I've also implemented a `ReferenceValidator` class like this:

```java
public class ReferenceValidator {

    public static Validation<String, ReferenceUniqueIdentifier> uniqueIdentifierNonNull(
            ReferenceUniqueIdentifier referenceUniqueIdentifier) {

        return Optional.ofNullable(referenceUniqueIdentifier)
                .map(Validation::<String, ReferenceUniqueIdentifier>valid)
                .orElse(Validation.invalid("Reference unique Identifier must be not null"));
    }

    public static Validation<String, TransactionId> transactionIdentifierNonNull(TransactionId transactionId) {

        return Optional.ofNullable(transactionId)
                .map(Validation::<String, TransactionId>valid)
                .orElse(Validation.invalid("Transaction identifier must be not null"));
    }

...

}
```

From my `Reference` class I've implemented a factory method like this:

```java
    public Validation<Seq<String>, Reference> of(ReferenceUniqueIdentifier referenceUniqueIdentifier,
            TransactionId transactionId) {
        Validation<String, ReferenceUniqueIdentifier> uniqueIdentifierNonNullValidation = ReferenceValidator
                .uniqueIdentifierNonNull(referenceUniqueIdentifier);
        Validation<String, TransactionId> transactionIdNonNullValidation = ReferenceValidator
                .transactionIdentifierNonNull(transactionId);
    //...How to combine 10 Validation<String, TField> into a single one?

    }
```

My question is, how could I combine my 10 or more relation `Validation<Error, ?>` into a single `Validation<Error, Reference>`?
Abocve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Normally...**

when combining `Validation` objects into a new `Validation` object you would use `Validation.combine` method in combination with the `ap` method. However, this combining allows for up to a max of `8` `Validation` objects in one go.

So for combining just 2 validations for example, you could do something like:

```java
 // ... the initial factory method implementation
 return Validation.combine(uniqueIdentifierNonNullValidation, transactionIdNonNullValidation)
                .ap(Reference::new); // or use a lambda instead of a method reference
```

**While in this case...**

the question is about combinding more than `8` validations, a bit more creativity might be required.

One way could be to first combine the first 5 validations into a `Tuple5` and then the next 5 validations into another `Tuple5` (or some other split if that makes more sense). And after that, combine the the validated `Tuple5` into the desired `Reference` object you were looking for, using a similar method as described above.

Something along these lines:

```java
  var firstValidatedFields = Validation.combine(
        uniqueIdentifierNonNullValidation,
        transactionIdNonNullValidation,
        documentIdValidation,
        field4Validation,
        field5Validation
  ).ap(Tuple5::new);
  var secondValidatedFields = Validation.combine(
        field6Validation,
        field7Validation,
        field8Validation,
        field9Validation,
        field10Validation
  ).ap(Tuple5::new);

  return firstValidatedFields.combine(secondValidatedFields)
          // Combine  the tuples
          .ap((t1, t2) -> new Reference(
              t1._1, t1._2, t1._3, t1._4, t1._5,
              t2._1, t2._2, t2._3, t2._4, t2._5
          ))
          // Flatten the otherwise nested errors
          .mapError(nestedErrors -> nestedErrors.flatMap(Function.identity()));
```

**Alternative**

An alternative option could be to look into the constructor arguments of the `Reference` objects to check whether some variables could be grouped into nested objects, which could bundle a few of these fields. These nested objects could then be assembled first by `combine(...).ap(..)` and then be combined into the final object.

For some classes it totally make sense to have some nested structure and for others it doesn't. You should check for yourself whether it's viable for this specific case.